# Не работает <Provider> в React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Все 5 ошибок появились при подключении Provider   [image: ошибки полученные при компиляции]
store создан при помощи функции createStore() и импортирован в компоненту, при октлючении Provider всё работет без каких либо проблем, но не отображается контент из store (по очевидным причинам).

```
<React.StrictMode>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <App />
                </Provider>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </React.StrictMode>
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем, разобрался, причины было две:

1. Открыл папку в которой находится проект, а не проект напрямую.
2. Устанавливал react-redux, а не react react-redux (т.е, фактически у меня не было либы react-redux вообще), после этого зарестартил весь проект и всё заработало.